# Creating A Website

Tags: raspbian, web-server

ok so, I have everything correct I think for port forwarding but the issue is that my pi (Raspberry pi 2B running RetroPie add-on on top of the regular Debian OS) is not opening the port that I have described on my router. the port taht I am having troubles to open is port 801 which I don't understand why it would have problems opening this port, I have no software that is installed to open this port and what not and when I try and do my public-ip-address:801 it keeps on loading and then it says "The connection has timed out" (I am on the newest version of FireFox when posting this post). I thought maybe its just my browser, so I tried a free domain name that I have and it has no luck connecting to it the message says the same thing. I have surfaced around the internet trying to see what I can do but no luck. Any help is appreciated also have a screen shot of what I am dealing with. (Sorry with the cringy editing)
[image][image][image]

Comment: source zone needs to be WAN, not LAN

Answer (score 1):

The "source zone" needs to be WAN and the destination zone needs to be LAN if you want to port forward from WAN to LAN

From the image, it's clear that the "source zone" is set to LAN, which is why it's not working